# wso2 identity server PAP,PDP,PEP caching

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

http://xacmlinfo.org/tag/pep-cache/
How to enable cacheing in PDP,PEP,PAP in wso2 identity server 4.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Identity server, you can find...  PDP level caching...  it means, there are three caches..

1. Policy cache -->  This is by default enable. All policies are stored in in-memory by default. You can not change any thing with this.
2. Decision cache -->  This is by default enable. You can configure it (enable/disable and cache timeout) using `entitlement.properties` file which can be found at `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/security` directory.
3. Attribute cache --> This is by default enable. You can configure it (enable/disable and cache timeout) using `entitlement.properties` file which can be found at `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/security` directory.

Policy and Decision caches are invalidated,  when policy update is detected. Also there are Web service API to clear these caches.

Comment: Hey Asela thanks for the reply.the above information resolved my issue.